# Windowing values from numpy 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, vectorization

I have an a 2D array of values,A. I want to window the values within this array around the index given by a 1D array,b.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.randint(1000, size=(100, 100))
b = np.random.randint(40,60, size=(100))
window = A[b[:]-10 : b[:]+10, :]
```

However, when running this I get the following error:

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

I've tried pre-allocating my window array using, but get the same error. I'm trying to avoid using a for loop and perform this vectorized.

Essentially I want to take the values of A for each column which are in a 20-row window around b.

```
print(b[:]-10,:)
```

gives:

> [47 40 46 30 42 36 48 33 37 41 49 31 41 40 39 48 39 48 42 37 48 37 31 32
>    49 43 32 39 45 41 30 48 30 46 31 39 48 44 36 30 40 45 47 34 49 46 41 43
>    30 38 31 35 42 48 49 42 32 33 42 48 48 39 31 32 45 39 36 49 31 44 48 30
>    33 47 33 48 36 38 42 30 49 43 41 34 39 49 39 45 42 38 39 45 47 40 46 35
>    41 39 47 38]

```
print(b[:]+10,:)
```

gives:

> [67 60 66 50 62 56 68 53 57 61 69 51 61 60 59 68 59 68 62 57 68 57 51 52
>    69 63 52 59 65 61 50 68 50 66 51 59 68 64 56 50 60 65 67 54 69 66 61 63
>    50 58 51 55 62 68 69 62 52 53 62 68 68 59 51 52 65 59 56 69 51 64 68 50
>    53 67 53 68 56 58 62 50 69 63 61 54 59 69 59 65 62 58 59 65 67 60 66 55
>    61 59 67 58]

I'd like to create a new 2D array which holds the values from A within this window of rows.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `b[:]-50 : b[:]+50`? Try printing `b[:]-50` and `b[:]+50`. You will see numbers which are beyond the indices of A. In questions like these, it is helpful in the interest of the time of readers to have some sample input and output. Otherwise, it wastes a lot of time of readers trying to interpret and decipher what you want. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What do you mean by "window"? Can you show us your expected result?

Comment: Regarding your comment, "_Your solution seems to drastically overcomplicate things. This shouldn't be too difficult._": no, it doesn't; yes, it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC here's one way to approach this:

```
A = np.random.randint(1000, size=(100, 100))
b = np.random.randint(40,60, size=(100))
```

Where `b` could be:

```
array([49, 47, 40, 44, 53, 47...
```

So given for example `b[0]`, IIUC you want to index `A[0]` from columns `39:59`, `A[1]` from `37:57` and so on... so first of all let's create an ndarray that will be used to index `A`:

```
ar = np.arange(-10, 11)
ix = np.add.outer(b,ar)

array([[39, 40, 41, ..., 57, 58, 59],
       [37, 38, 39, ..., 55, 56, 57],
       [30, 31, 32, ..., 48, 49, 50],
       ...,
```

Now we can use `ix` to index `A` and obtain a `(100, 20)` array with the columns of interest on each row. In order to do so we can use [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

```
A[np.arange(len(b))[:,None], ix][:,:-1]

array([[448, 963, 199, ...,  40, 300, 623],
       [258, 905, 862, ..., 517, 671, 399],
       [629, 408,  83, ..., 490, 883,  68],
       ...,
       [188, 368, 598, ..., 579, 925, 739],
       [131, 318,  28, ..., 444, 487, 362],
       [135, 801, 123, ..., 308, 579,  41]])
```